# use addSubtitleSource with videoview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add subtitle to videoview
and the method of getSubtitleSource is like this:

```
private InputStream getSubtitleSource(String filepath) {
        InputStream ins = null;
        String ccFileName = filepath.substring(0,filepath.lastIndexOf('.'));
        File file = new File(ccFileName);
        if (file.exists() == false)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"no close caption file " + ccFileName);
            return null;
        }
        FileInputStream fins = null;
        try {
            fins = new FileInputStream(file);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"exception " + e);
        }
        ins = (InputStream)fins;
        return ins;
    }
```

and here how I call the method and use srt file with it:

```
videoView.seekTo(position);
String srt = "http://shasha/share/2018/09/07/Lucha_Mexico_.srt";
videoView.addSubtitleSource(getSubtitleSource(srt),MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/srt",Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage())); 
videoView.start();
```

there is a problem with addSubtitleSource and createSubtitleFormat says:

> Call requires API level 19 (current min is 16):
>   android.widget.VideoView#addSubtitleSource

so I just surrounded it with sdk version like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
videoView.seekTo(position);
String srt = "http://shasha/share/2018/09/07/Lucha_Mexico_.srt";
videoView.addSubtitleSource(getSubtitleSource(srt),MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/srt",Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()));  
videoView.start();
 }
```

but when I play the video there is no subtitle appear so what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

Checking with Build.VERSION just escaping your app from crashing.Therefore if you are using a device lower than api level 19, the app will not crash but the getSubTitleSource will not work.

Just edit your minSdkVersion in app.gradle with api level 19.

```
  minSdkVersion 19
```

Comment: actually my device android version is 7.0 which mean it's api is 24 but the subtitle doesn't work on it @Sana

Comment: I will check on it again later today.